# SAPUI5 this.getView in attachRequestCompleted

Tags: sapui5

I am loading data to my model and have a attachRequestCompleted attached. In there I want to set a value to one field, but it returns *this.getView is not a function.* This whole thing is inside a an interval:
My code looks like this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(this.readRfid.bind(this), 3000);

readRfid: function() {

var oRfidModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();

    oRfidModel.loadData("http://localhost/xxxxxxx");    
    oRfidModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {

      var reader = oRfidModel.oData.children["0"].children["0"].innerHTML;    
      this.getView().byId("objHdr_det_id1").setNumberUnit(reader);
});
```

Can I not use this.getView in the function? How can I make it work?
Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` instance is not pointing to the Controller.
You probably need to bind a context to the callback function you've passed to the `attachRequestCompleted`.

As you can see [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#attachRequestCompleted) you can pass an oListener to this method.

I guess that something like:

```
    var oRfidModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();

    oRfidModel.loadData("http://localhost/xxxxxxx");    
    oRfidModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {

       var reader = oRfidModel.oData.children["0"].children["0"].innerHTML;    
       this.getView().byId("objHdr_det_id1").setNumberUnit(reader);

    }, this);
```

Would work.
If this does not help you you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) a context to the callback.